# Peculiar behavior of an infinite product of the function $\tan(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product

I am trying to express $\tan(x)$ as an infinite product.
So far I have found 4 factors
$$x\frac{(\frac{x^2-\pi^2}{\pi^2})(\frac{x^2-4\pi^2}{1})(\frac{x^2-9\pi^2}{1})(\frac{x^2-16\pi^2}{1})}{1.33554327...(x^2-\frac{\pi^2}{4})(x^2-\frac{9\pi^2}{4})(x^2-\frac{25\pi^2}{4})(x^2-\frac{49\pi^2}{4})}$$

As you can see, I have accounted for the zeroes at $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$.. and asymptotes at $\frac{\pi}{2}$...$\space$ However when I try to scale it down with more than 2 $\pi$'s as shown above, I see that the function becomes too curved and does not match up, it only seems to line up when I divide by another number $1.33554327...$. I am unsure as to where this number comes from and I would like to know why dividing by $\pi$, $2\pi$.. does not help match the function with $\tan(x)$ and how to scale the product (what should I divide the top factors by?)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Have a look at the infinite product formulae for sine and cosine here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Comment: Since you only have a *finite* product, an adjustment is to be expected.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948987/409) mentions the product $$\tan(x)=\frac{x\;\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2k-1)^2\pi^2}\right)}$$ (dividing the product for $\sin x$ by the product for $\cos x$). Comparing its four-factor finite form to yours should help explain how that constant arises.

Comment: If you divide through carefully, your constant is actually $\frac43$.

Comment: what is the pattern in which i have to divide by?